# C++ openssl: setting list of ciphers

Tags: c++, openssl

I have very basic C++ application that uses openssl library. Application sends request to server and the list of ciphersuites have to be the next:

**4865-4866-4867-49195-49199-49196-49200-52393-52392-49171-49172-156-157-47-53**

Using SSL_set_cipher_list and SSL_set_ciphersuites I am setting list of ciphers. But when I use next list:
**TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384**

**TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256**

**TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256**

**TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256**

**TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384**

**TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384**

**TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256**

**TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256**

**TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA**

**TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA**

**TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256**

**TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384**

**TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA**

**TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA**

I am getting **4865-4866-4867-49195-49199-49196-49200-52393-52392-49171-49172-156-157-47-53-255**. But I cannot understand where **255** in the end come from ? It shouldn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

255 is a special cipher suit identifier. Reading RFCs when you deal with security is always useful.

[RFC5746](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746)

> **3.3.  Renegotiation Protection Request Signaling Cipher Suite Value**
> Both the SSLv3 and TLS 1.0/TLS 1.1 specifications require implementations to ignore data following the ClientHello (i.e., extensions) if they do not understand it.  However, some SSLv3 and TLS 1.0 implementations incorrectly fail the handshake in such a case.  This means that clients that offer the "renegotiation_info" extension may encounter handshake failures.  In order to enhance compatibility with such servers, this document defines a second signaling mechanism via a special Signaling Cipher Suite Value (SCSV) "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV", with code point {0x00, 0xFF}. This SCSV is not a true cipher suite (it does not correspond to any valid set of algorithms) and cannot be negotiated.  Instead, it has the same semantics as an empty "renegotiation_info" extension, as described in the following sections.  Because SSLv3 and TLS implementations reliably ignore unknown cipher suites, the SCSV may be safely sent to any server.  The SCSV can also be included in the SSLv2 backward compatible CLIENT-HELLO (see Appendix E.2 of [RFC5246]).

Now you know the name TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV and you can try to exclude it. But this may be not working.

Comment: thanks! Can you please help me, what is correct way to remove TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV ?
Using just '!' in string does not works

Comment: No way, is possible only in obsolete versions. You should not worry about this. Useful reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35421474/6752050